# Query get category and product on tree

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have category table:

[image]

And product table:

[image]

I want query get a tree include both category and product, example: If last level of category is product of category, same image below:

[image]

Comment: Consider adding the SQL you have tried so far [mcve]. BTW I would go with recursive CTE (in SQL Server are called that way), not sure is memsql has them implemented tho.

Comment: Sorry, I use mysql and i have added the wrong add tag memsql, can you give me a example about it?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Thanks you **@bradbury9**

I try JOIN 2 table and use UNION ALL, it working for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
     (
          (
                SELECT NULL AS content_id, NULL AS question, NULL AS answer, node.*, 
                     (
                          SELECT COUNT(parent1.id) - 1
                          FROM faq_categories AS node1,
                          faq_categories AS parent1
                          WHERE node1.lft BETWEEN parent1.lft AND parent1.rgt AND node1.id = node.id
                          GROUP BY node1.name
                          ORDER BY node1.lft
                     ) AS level
               FROM `faq_contents` as content
               LEFT JOIN `faq_categories` AS node ON node.`id` = content.`category_id`
               LEFT JOIN `faq_categories` AS parent ON parent.`id` = content.`category_id`
               WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
               GROUP BY node.id

           )
           UNION ALL
           (
                 SELECT content.id AS content_id, content.question, content.answer, node.*, 
                       (
                             CASE WHEN content.id IS NULL THEN
                             (
                                  SELECT COUNT(parent1.id) - 1
                                  FROM faq_categories AS node1,
                                       faq_categories AS parent1
                                  WHERE node1.lft BETWEEN parent1.lft AND parent1.rgt AND node1.id = node.id
                                  GROUP BY node1.name
                                  ORDER BY node1.lft
                              )
                              ELSE 3 END
                       ) AS level
                  FROM `faq_contents` AS content
                  RIGHT JOIN `faq_categories` AS node ON node.`id` = content.`category_id`
           )
   ) node
ORDER BY lft
```